# Plots and buttons within plots with Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, button

I'm trying to teach myself how to integrate `plots` and `buttons`, and by that extension, actually programme using `Classes`.

The challenge I set myself was to:

1. Create a scatter plot (Done)
2. Create a button that produces a new scatter plot within the existing scatter plot (Done)
3. Create a button within the new scatter plot (Done)
4. Assign the new button the functionality of closing the new scatter plot (Stuck here)

This is my progress so far:

[image]

My code below:

Any hints are welcomed!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


  # Junk data for the purpose of my question

x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots()

ax1.scatter(x, y)  # plot (x, y) data as a scatter plot

class Initial_plot(object):

    def close_plot(self, event):
        plt.close()

    def add_axis(self, event):
        plt.axes([0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.51])

        x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
        y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

        plt.scatter(x, y)

        class Second_plot(object):

            def close_addplot(self, event):
                plt.close()


          # Button to close the new scatter plot
        axclose_addplot = plt.axes([0.4, 0.4, 0.15, 0.1])
        bclose_addplot = Button(axclose_addplot, 'Close add plot')
        bclose_addplot.on_clicked(callback.close_addplot)


callback = Initial_plot()


  # Add button for a new scatter plot

axadd_plot = plt.axes([0.5, 0.01, 0.1, 0.071])
badd_plot = Button(axadd_plot, 'Add Plot')
badd_plot.on_clicked(callback.add_axis)



  # Exit Button for inital scatter plot
axclose_plot = plt.axes([0.7, 0.01, 0.1, 0.071])  # co-ords of button
bclose_plot = Button(axclose_plot, 'Close')  # name of button
bclose_plot.on_clicked(callback.close_plot)  # enables event upon clicking the button

plt.show()  #display the plot
```